# ACF don't save the selected value

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

firstly i created a select dropdownlist using acf that dynamically populate like this:

```
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=chef', 'my_acf_load_chef_field');

function my_acf_load_chef_field( $field )
{    
    $user_fields = array( 'user_login');
    $argu = new WP_User_Query( array( 'role' => 'chef' , 'fields' => $user_fields ));
    $choices = $argu->get_results();
    //$choices = get_field($field['choices'], $post->ID , false);
    $field['choices'] = array();  
     if( is_array($choices) ) {
        $len = count($choices);
        for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
            array_push($field['choices'], ($choices[$i]->user_login));
    }
   }
    return $field;
```

and it worked well in retrieving data 
but when i select the wanted chef it save my ACF key instead of the value in post meta value field_5cf49fa0651bb like this

i want to insert the selected value in mysql

Comment: Can you give an example. I don't understand what you mean with ACF key. Give me an example of the array `$choices` and give me an example of the desired result. Add them both to your question, not in comments please.

Comment: my example is written in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55982412/load-my-user-login-from-database-into-my-acf-select-field-code/55982681?noredirect=1#comment98615406_55982681 now i already get the choices in my select menu from users that have a chef role but in mysql when i'm tried to get the values of my advanced custom field (ACF) to make the user select his chef to make order the meta value is written as a my custom field key field_5cf49fa0651bb not the selected chef